# i encounterd a list index out of range error ,my view is as follows;

Tags: django, view

def login_view(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
return redirect('/dashboard')

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    cache.set('email',email)
    fact = User.objects.filter(email=email).values('username')
    username = fact[0]['username']
    username = username.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
    password = password.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: There is no `User` for the given `email`. That is what the error is saying.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a check to see wether your filter query returned any data:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    cache.set('email',email)
    fact = User.objects.filter(email=email).values('username')
    if len(fact) > 0:
        username = fact[0]['username']
        username = username.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
        password = password.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
    else:
        print("no user")
```